# Spring boot: can a springboot app be deployed to upcloud or vultr cloud services

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to host my spring boot app, based on the documentation of spring boot they mention Heroku, AWS, Google Cloud, google cloud as some of the host providers. I want to know if Springboot apps can be hosted also on Vultr and Upcloud and any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot is a simple java application can be deployed in any cloud. please specify if you have some specific concern.

Please look into this link:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

Comment: Okay, i have actually converted my app into a fat Jar, i have set up the azure server and i can remote to it, problem now is i do not have any idea on what to do next

Comment: Ok, so you need help in deployment. I can try to help you. connect me on pandeymradul@gmail.com